WinUI3 x:Bind being batched/slow to update the UI
I am attempting to stream tokens from an LLM to a WinUI3 RichTextBlock.
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="2" Margin="15" Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.ShowPlaceholder, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <RichTextBlock >
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Summary, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </RichTextBlock>
        </ScrollView>

The ViewModel is implemented using the Community Toolkit ObservableObject as a base class.
I have a service which will give a callback with the next token as it's received:
                var result = await service.StreamContentSummary(
                    ...,
                    (text) =>
                {
                    dispatcher.TryEnqueue(() =>
                    {
                        if (done)
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                        that.ShowPlaceholder = false;
                        that.Summary = $"{that.Summary}{text}";
                    });
                },
                refresh);

ShowPlaceholder and Summary are ObservableProperties to which the UI is bound.
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string summary;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool showPlaceholder = true;

I directly attached a listener to PropertyChanged on the ViewModel, and can see that as expected, it is being invoked for each new token added to the Summary, however the UI itself doesn't show each token as it's added; instead, the UI doesn't seem to update until the entire response has finished, with the same user experience as no streaming at all.
I tried calling this.Bindings.Update() in the component to force the bindings to update in each PropertyChanged event, but the UI still doesn't seem to refresh to show the content until after everything is done.
    In Loaded...
    ViewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModel_PropertyChanged;

...

    private void ViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ViewModel.Summary))
        {
            this.Bindings.Update();
        }
    }

I also tried switching the {x:Bind} bindings to {Binding} and that didn't help any.
Does WinUI3 do some kind of batching to limit the rate of updates?  Is there a way to force the UI to update when the Summary property changes in realtime, or is there an alternative approach to accomplish "streaming" updates to the UI?
Here is a sample project which exhibits the same "instant" behavior https://github.com/rcbevans/StreamingTokenText.
I am struggling to capture some of the complexity of the original code which is generating each "token" by reading server side events from a HttpResponse.Content Stream using ReadAsync in 32 byte chunks until a new complete line is ready, then parsing the JSON to get the next token.
In the sample project, as in the real code, if I add Thread.Sleep(1) to the substring task, I do see the content type out rather than just appear.  If I do Thread.Sleep(0) it is still instant.  I believe that the lowest resolution for C# sleep is actually 16.67ms, and not the 1ms asked for.
If I add a Thread.sleep(1); periodically only when i % 5, 30, 100 == 0 or similar, I then see the text appearing in increasingly larger chunks proportional to the modulus, again suggesting that this periodic delay is what triggers the UI to actually update.
The alternate version of StreamResponse explicitly creating a new thread each time also "types" out the content, presumably because the overhead of creating a new thread each iteration is introducing a sufficient delay that whatever batching or debouncing I feel like I'm seeing is not happening.
One thing that I'm not sure how to accurately measure in the real code is the time delta between the first token being ready, the entire response being complete, and the UI being updated to show the completed response.  It's possible that there's something going on in terms of the network request and subsequent stream reading that means the "streamed" response content is actually being read one line at a time from an already complete response, so the actual incremental reading and parsing is effectively instantaneous.

The x:Bind seems correct. You just need to set the text to Summary and should be rendered. You don't need Bindings.Update(). What happens if you place a breakpoint inside the TryEnqueue()? Does it actually set a non-empty text to Summary? Also, have you tried removing the ScrollView visibility switching?

The behavior looks like the processing blocks the UI thread. Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information? You could simulate the task of the service with a new thread.

Yes, service.StreamContentSummary is running inside a Task.Run() which has var that = this; before.  Summary is also set after the full summary is returned from the Task.

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT the loading UI is animated and seems fully responsive.  I checked with the debugger that the PropertyChanged is firing for each incremental update to the Summary property, and that it's firing on the dispatcher thread (it is, if I remove dispatcher.TryEnqueue I get COM Exceptions which is what I would expect, trying to update bound properties on a non-dispatcher thread.

I added a Thread.Sleep into the StreamContentSummary loop where it is reading the server side events and deserializing them to artificially slow it down, and then I see the tokens appear incrementally as expected, confirming that the code itself is "fine", but that it's some kind of issue with the UI not synchronously updating when the property itself is set.

It's better to exclude the server and simulate the task with a thread modifying the summary string to provide a minimal, reproducible sample.

A program such as this works fine https://pastebin.com/raw/8bL8hxMJ the problem probably resides in details of your code that we don't see. Please provide a fully reproducing project.

This exhibits the same behavior https://github.com/rcbevans/StreamingTokenText

You weren't addressing me, so I wasn't aware you posted somethinhg. Now, what's the problem you see exactly with this code?

As you said, the code itself is "fine" while the behavior the UI shows could be due to

DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue Adds a task to the DispatcherQueue that will be executed on the thread associated with the DispatcherQueue and there is priority of the task (such as Low, Normal, or High).
The execution of tasks is too fast and your main UI thread executes OutputText = fullResponse; finally which could discard preceding messages.

Commenting out the line OutputText = fullResponse; or dispatching High priority messages makes the UI look more smooth.
